# Using Android NDK on Windows without Cygwin?

Tags: windows, android-ndk, cygwin

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the NDK from Eclipse without having Cygwin installed?  If not, what do I need to do in the Eclipse IDE to call the ndk-build executable from within Cygwin?

I ask because I get all kinds of 'invalid directory' messages when I try to compile sample NDK apps, owing to spaces in the directory paths.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on googlecode called  vs-android that lets you build from visual studio, without cygwin.
I recently downloaded the lastest version of the ndk for windows and noticed that it includes a ndk-build.cmd that seems to let you build from windows cli. I need to give that a spin.
edit : it worked for me :)